# Interop UserControl acts different in .NET and COM

Tags: .net, com, user-controls, vb6

I've got an UserControl that works in a quite strange way. By calling a method, the control opens an application in background, take the handle of a form and adds the main control of that last to its own controls. This is the last piece of the code i used:

```
Dim controlHandle As IntPtr = New IntPtr(WinHandle)
Dim controlWin As Control = Control.FromHandle(controlHandle)
Dim controlView As Control = controlWin.Controls("viewSitePanel")
controlView.Dock = DockStyle.Fill
Controls.Add(controlView)
```

The `controlView` contains another UserControl with a grid dinamically populated. In a .NET application I can see the rows of the grid, but when I use the control in a COM application I can't see any row! I used the `VB6 Interop UserControl` element from the `Microsoft InteropForms Toolkit 2.1` to create my control... Somehow it seems like a refresh or similar is not happening... The `controlView` also contains a detail view with fields dinamically populated and also them don't work... I've got other grids and fields that work inside that control...

I don't know where to start to debug!

Thank you.

Comment: The code snippet is filled to the brim with code-smells.  Very unclear why you have to hack it this way.  Randomly add Me.Show() to this snippet, some odds that you'll now see that control.

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand what "code-smells" means (english is not my first language). Anyway, I can explain why I need this code. The application I developed uses DevExpress ExpressApp Framework (XAF). The "form" (actually a [DashBoardView](https://documentation.devexpress.com/#xaf/clsDevExpressExpressAppDashboardViewtopic)) is dinamically created by that framework. I want to show part of it in a VB6 application. My solution is the only one that came to my mind... Why should I add Me.Show() and where? The control is already shown, but the grid is not automatically refreshed.