# Reparent controls from a .NET form to VB6

Tags: vb.net, vb6

Good morning. I've got an interop .NET form that I can create and show inside a VB6 project. Now, I would like to open the form in "MDI mode". I've got a control that allows me to achieve this result. Unfortunatly it seems to work only with standard VB6 forms. So, the test I would like to try is to copy the content of the .NET form inside the VB6 one... Do you have any suggestion on how to deal with this situation?
Thank you!

Comment: So do you have an MDI parent from in VB6 and you want to open a VB.NET form as an MDI Child?

Comment: Yes. But I need to open a VB6 form as an MDI Child. The VB.NET form should be copied in this last.

Comment: You can't host a form inside a form (AFAIK) your solution is to use a UserControl

Comment: To be honest, I solved using the SetParent API. But I've got one new problem related to the keyboard. I can't insert text in other MDI child when I open the one incorporating the .NET form...

Comment: @ufo That's probably because you are using SetParent(). All it does is to move a child window to another parent. All the Windows messaging is unaffected. So any notifications from the child window to the parent are lost - for instance keyboard notifications. Also, it is pretty dangerous if you are using SetParent() to a window in a different thread/process. The code isn't expecting a child window to be there, and this could lead to weird bugs. Nor will the VB6 or .NET runtime realise that the child window has moved, which could cause errors in *that* code.

Comment: @MarkBertenshaw and MattWilko, first of all, thanks for the help.
I don't think SetParent is the problem. I suspect is something related to the ActiveXControlHelpers class from the _InteropForms Toolkit 2.1_.

This is the code I used:
`'START .NET INTEROP FORM
>Set NETForm = New NETInteropForm
    
>NETForm.CreateControl
>NETForm.FormBorderStyle = NONE
>NETForm.WindowState = vbMaximized
    
>NETForm.Initialize param1, param2
>NETForm.OpenView viewName
 
>SetParent FrmFermiPerOper.Handle, Me.hWnd
>FrmFermiPerOper.Show
>'END .NET INTEROP FORM`

If I use ShowDialog instead of Show it works.

Answer (score 1):

The way you are doing this is asking for trouble - it's a bit hacky. It would be better to use supported mechanisms as far as possible.

You would be better off if you create a .NET UserControl with the GUI you want to display, and make it COM visible. You then can instantiate the control in a VB6 form, which would fully support the way that MDI is supported in VB6.

Comment: I'm using a Form instead of a UserControl to avoid the problems mentioned here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22509843/interop-usercontrol-acts-different-in-net-and-com

Comment: @ufo The question on the link you provided is not describing what I have suggested. That seems to be doing something rather hacky, not that it was obvious what you were attempting. My suggestion is fully supported by the .NET framework.

Comment: Yes, I know... But using the XAF Framework, as stated in the link, I can't think of a different solution...